# Python Selenium - How to pass UnexpectedAlertPresentException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, exception

Im trying to automate a web-game with python using selenium webdriver. There you have some missions and you have to send specific vehicles to a mission. You've a button where you can click on to choose a vehicle. If a vehicle is'nt available, a alert will present.

And that's the problem. I get an UnexpectedAlertPresentException and I tried to pass it like this:

```
try:
   acc_veh_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='tab- 
   content']/div[{}]/div[1]/div[*]/a[@title='{}']".format(tab_index, acc_veh_name.strip())).click()
   sleep(0.1)
except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
   alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
   alert.accept()
   veh_ava = False
   pass
else:
   pass
```

I don't know if this is the right way to handle this... anyway I get an UnexpectedAlertPresentException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is... simple. The alert took to long to appear so the alert came when the program wasnt in the try/except. Also the switch to the alert wasnt needed. It close everythings on his own

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command for Python to press the "enter" key on the keyboard and confirm "ok" in the message box that appears on the page after the search:

import keyboard

keyboard.press("enter")
keyboard.release("enter")

After the box closes and you can continue the code